# How to insert data in audit table using trigger if value is changed without check condition

Tags: postgresql

I have one table with 25 fields. I want to update some log if the value of any of the 25 fields are changed. I can do with `OLD. != New`. but I have to write 25 condition which is not an elegant solution. I can also do it by using `OLD` `NEW` but it is inserting a date even if no data has been updated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to detect changes in 25 fields, you need to check 25 fields. What is the problem with that?

Comment: Does `(NEW.*) <> (OLD.*)` work?

Comment: 25 condition is not good standards

Comment: Does (NEW.*) <> (OLD.*) work?  - yup its working but its inserting even I have not changed anything

Comment: try `new is distinct from old`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by using

WHEN ( (OLD.col1, OLD.col2, OLD.col3) IS DISTINCT FROM (NEW.col1, NEW.col2, NEW.col3) )